# Find the location of a currently open file in Keynote

Tags: macos, iwork-keynote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell full path of file on Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/371513/how-to-tell-full-path-of-file-on-mac)

If I've got a file open in Keynote (and probably other iWork apps), how can I discover where that file is located on disk?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, hang on, figured it out.

Control+Click ('right click') on the filename above the toolbar. The path appears as a list.